# How to make a method (function) call of parent form from a child form

Tags: c++, forms, clr

I write the application in C++ (CLR). It's an application with forms.

I have 2 forms: `MainForm` and `ExtensionsForm`. `MainForm` is shown when the program is started. When you click on the button, `ExtensionsForm` will be created.

Also I have these files: `MainForm.h`, `MainForm.cpp`, `ExtensionsForm.h`, `ExtensionsForm.cpp`.

To create form `ExtensionsForm`, I've added this to beginning of the file `MainForm.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "ExtensionsForm.h" // <-- added
```

In `MainForm` in button onClick event handler to open `ExtensionsForm` I've added this:

```
ExtensionsForm^ extensionsForm = gcnew ExtensionsForm();
extensionsForm->ShowDialog();
```

And this code works correctly.

But I need to make some changes in the appearance of the `MainForm` after clicking the button in `ExtensionsForm`. How can I implement this correctly?

Thank you in advance!

**My attempt**

I've created the method (function) in `MainForm` and I tried to call this method in `ExtensionsForm`. I can use the constructor to pass the reference, but anyway I have an error:
[image]

How to solve this?

**My solution**

I've included all `*.h` files in `Main.cpp` file. Inside `Main.cpp` I have this:

```
#include "MainForm.h"
#include "ExtensionsForm.h"
```

After that, if I want to make changes on another form (for example, I can press the button on the `ExtensionsForm` and changes must appear on the `MainForm`), I can do just this:

1. I can create `public` method inside `MainForm.h`, which makes some changes on this form. My example:

   ```
   public: void updateButton(int amount, int maxAmount) {
       button->Text = amount + " / " + maxAmount;
   }
   public: void updateTextBox(String^ text) {
       textBox->Text = text;
   }
   ```
2. To show a new form, I can use the method inside `MainForm.cpp`. My example:

   ```
   #include "MainForm.h"
   #include "ExtensionsForm.h"

   namespace FileFinder {

       [STAThreadAttribute]
       int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
       {
           Application::EnableVisualStyles();
           Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           FileFinder::MainForm mainForm;
           Application::Run(%mainForm);
           return 0;
       }
       void MainForm::buttonExtensions_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
           ExtensionsForm^ extensionsForm = gcnew ExtensionsForm();
           extensionsForm->Owner = this;
           extensionsForm->ShowDialog();
       }
   }
   ```

   Method `buttonExtensions_Click` implemented (defined) here. Also it has definition in `MainForm.h`:

   `private: void buttonExtensions_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);`

   This works perfectly, but you must implement (define) your method in `*.cpp` file, which includes your `*.h` file or inside this `*.h` file (the definition must exist). Also you can see `extensionsForm->Owner = this;` in this method. This is necessary for the next step.
3. After this things, you can use something like this inside `ExtensionsForm.h`:

   ```
   private: void buttonConfirmExtensions_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
       MainForm^ mainForm = (MainForm^)this->Owner;
       mainForm->updateButtonExtensions(checkedExtensionsCount, extensionsCount);
       mainForm->updateTextBoxExtensions(textBoxExtensionsString);
       this->Close();
   }
   ```

   You can get your `MainForm` by `Owner` and use defined `public` methods of this form. That's all.

Comment: This is a very traditional hangup in C++, you have a circular dependency between the two .h files.  Fixing this requires doing the C++ dance with forward declarations and moving code from the .h file to the .cpp file.  But the correct way to do this is to pay attention to the return value of ShowDialog().  If it is DialogResult::Ok then update whatever needs to be updated from the dialog form class.  Or in other words, MainForm needs to update itself.  Using the properties you expose on your ExtensionForm class.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you! I'm a little familiar with C++. And you solve this problem for me. Can you write this as an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was solved by relocating some code to `.cpp` file.

Hans Passant, thanks for the advice.